# Setter is not returning the expected output

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter, setter

I've tried trouble shooting this with essentially the exact same issue on codecademy to no avail. I'm trying to get my javascript setter to check whether the argument I am passing in is a number, and if the conditions are satisfied set it to the class property, else return an error string.

I can't understand why this isn't working and I've spent several long hours on it already, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get age() {
    return this._age;
  }

  set age(num) {
    if (num.isNaN()) {
      console.log('error!')
    } else {
      this._age = num
    }
  }
}

let human = new Person('Armand', 'string');

console.log(human);
```

Comment: You're never getting nor setting `name` nor `age` properties anywhere - you're only assigning to `_name` or `_age` (you may as well remove all code that isn't in the constructor ATM)

Comment: when you do get it running, it will error out because a string does not have isNaN() method

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about ... I clearly declared my getters ... this is JS you're talking about right? @CertainPerformance

Comment: In order to invoke a getter, you need to reference the getter's property name, eg `let human = new Person(...); human.name;`. Declaring your getters isn't enough, if you want to interact with them, you also need to call them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire the setter function inside the constructor, you should not use the backing field property (`this._age`) inside the constructor. Remove the underscore. ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set))

Furthermore, string does not have the `isNan()` method rather, it takes the variable as an argument like the code below. ([Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp))

If you want a begginer's guide to Javascript ES6 Class Syntax, you should check [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax) out. Thanks :)

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  get age() {
    return this._age;
  }

  set age(numeric) {
    if (isNaN(numeric)) {
      console.log('error!')
    } else {
      this._age = numeric
    }
  }

  set name(newName) {
    this._name = newName;
  }
}

let human = new Person('Armand', 'string');
console.log(human);
```